# Displaying one image - load from a set

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a jquery function where I have a sidebar on the right with a bunch of images with:

Title
About Text

On the right it shows them all, then if you click one it shows the image larger on the left with the text. And if you click another it transition in to that other one.

I could set up a bunch of elements and grab the child elements which would be the title and about text store in a variable then append to the element to display it.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/demo_02.htm

Code is available at: http://code.google.com/p/galleria/